# Javascript - Both if and else statements executing

Tags: javascript, debugging

My code is trying to assemble a visual chessboard of the given size, and then output it to `console.log`. Basically, it:

- Loops through all of the rows in the board
- Loops through all of the all of the columns in the row
- If the column place is even in an even row, it places a white space
- If the column place is even in an odd row, it places a black space.

My code:

```js
var sz = Number(prompt("What size chessboard?"))
console.log("Board of size " + sz + " selected.") 
var row = 0
var rowType = "even"
var col = 0
var bd = ""
var whiteSpace = "[]"
var blackSpace = "()"

for (row; row <= sz; row++) {
  if (row % 2 == 0) {rowType = "even";}  // For even rows, all even column places are white
  else {rowType = "odd";}  // and for odd rows, all even column places are black
  for (col = 0; col <= sz; col++) {
    if (col % 2 == 0) {
      if (rowType == "even") {bd += whiteSpace;}
      if (rowType == "odd") {bd += blackSpace;}
      else {console.log("Something went terribly wrong.")}  // This should never happen... right?
    }
    else {
      if (rowType == "even") {bd += blackSpace;}
      if (rowType == "odd") {bd += whiteSpace;}
      else {console.log("Something went horribly wrong.")}  // Not this one either?
    }
  }
  bd += "\n"
}
console.log(bd)
```

For some reason though, the extra code I put in just to catch the case of if, somehow, `rowType` was not either "even" or "odd" always seems to execute, putting "Something went terribly/horribly wrong" in `console.log` even though the code works fine and *the board is actually produced correctly.*

My problem isn't so much how to get rid of those lines, as obviously I could just remove the `else` block, but I'm curious as to where my mistake is that makes it run in the first place.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add your code to the question

Comment: You have two `if`s in a row, and the first one doesn’t have an `else`. Did you mean `else if`?

Comment: Also, you can write it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jjg5ahLb/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have it, you're doing:

```
if (rowType == "even") {bd += whiteSpace;}
if (rowType == "odd") {bd += blackSpace;}
else {console.log("Something went terribly wrong.")} // <- will execute if
                                                     //    not 'odd'
```

That should be:

```
if (rowType == "even") {bd += whiteSpace;}
else if (rowType == "odd") {bd += blackSpace;}
else {console.log("Something went terribly wrong.")} // <- will execute if
                                                     //    not 'even' or 'odd'
```